# Critical Tunnel failure exception. How to solve this

Tags: url, blackberry, connection

I wrote the below code to send location coordinates to server:

```
setTitle("version 5.0");
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    criteria.setHorizontalAccuracy(Criteria.NO_REQUIREMENT);
    criteria.setVerticalAccuracy(Criteria.NO_REQUIREMENT);
    criteria.setCostAllowed(true);
    criteria.setPreferredPowerConsumption(Criteria.POWER_USAGE_LOW);

   // bc.setFailoverMode(GPSInfo.GPS_MODE_ssCDMA_MS_ASSIST, 2, 100);
    try {
        LocationProvider lp=LocationProvider.getInstance(criteria);
        if(lp !=null)
        {
        Location loc=null;
    //  while(loc==null)
    //  {   
            loc=lp.getLocation(-1);
    //  }
        if(loc!=null){
            add(new EditField(loc.getQualifiedCoordinates().getLatitude()+"\n"+loc.getQualifiedCoordinates().getLongitude(),""));
        }
        else 
            add(new EditField("unable to find the location provider", ""));
        }
        else
        {
        add(new EditField("unable to find the location provider", ""));
        }
    } catch (LocationException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    ButtonField b = new ButtonField("Send");
    add(b);
    b.setChangeListener(new FieldChangeListener() {

        public void fieldChanged(Field field, int context) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            try{
                String url="http://56.91.532.72:8084/SFTS/updateLocation.jsp?empid=12304&lat=16.9477&lon=82.23970;deviceside=true";
                Dialog.alert(url);
                ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();

                 // use the factory to get a connection
                 ConnectionDescriptor conDescriptor = factory.getConnection(url, TransportInfo.TRANSPORT_TCP_CELLULAR,null);


                 if ( conDescriptor != null ) {
                    HttpConnection  conn = (HttpConnection) conDescriptor.getConnection();  
                    Dialog.alert("http");
                    //conn.setRequestMethod(HttpConnection.GET);
                    Dialog.alert("conn.setre");
                    int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
                    Dialog.alert(Integer.toString(responseCode));
                    if(responseCode == HttpConnection.HTTP_OK)
                    {
                        Dialog.alert("OK");
                        InputStream data = conn.openInputStream();
                        StringBuffer raw = new StringBuffer();
                        byte[] buf = new byte[4096];
                        int nRead = data.read(buf);
                        while(nRead > 0)
                        {
                            raw.append(new String(buf, 0, nRead));
                            nRead = data.read(buf);
                        }

                    }
                }
            }catch(Exception e){
                    Dialog.alert(e.getMessage());
                }
        }
    });
```

I am getting an exception Critical tunnel failure. But i am able to retrieve the location coordinates correctly. I am using blackberry 8520 with airtel sim which is enabled with data services. Actually this app worked well in the mobile with version 5.0. But it's not working in the mobile which i've upgraded from 4.6.1.3 to 5.0.0 what might be the problem? Please provide me a solution. thank you

I also tried the below url's:

1. http://56.91.532.72:8084/SFTS/updateLocation.jsp?empid=12304&lat=16.9477&lon=82.23970;deviceside=true;apn=null
2. http://56.91.532.72:8084/SFTS/updateLocation.jsp?empid=12304&lat=16.9477&lon=82.23970;deviceside=true;apn=airtelgprs.com

I also enabled apn settings in my mobile

Comment: More information: do you get the Critical Tunnel failure every time you execute this code, or does it start after some time?

Comment: It comes everytime i run the code

Answer (score 1):

It is because you haven't set up the apn correctly. As you are using direct tcp, the apn has to be set in order to connect to the network.

Also , network connections should be done on a separate thread.

Comment: Try this connection string, then: `http://56.91.532.72:8084/SFTS/updateLocation.jsp?empid=12304&lat=16.9477&lon=82.23970;deviceside=true;apn=airtelgprs.com`

Comment: I've tried running the network connection on a separate thread. The result is same. Even i tried the above url

Comment: Same problem even when i used interface=wifi;apn=airtelgprs.com and only interface=wifi

Comment: just use interface=wifi, and remove apn=airtelgprs.com . Also running the newtwork connection on separate thread will not solve the issue of tunnel failure. You always have to run network connections on separate thread.

Comment: Yes. It is working when i used only interface=wifi. But i don't want to connect with wifi. I want to use gprs

Comment: if you want to use gprs then either setup apn by following http://btsc.webapps.blackberry.com/btsc/search.do?cmd=displayKC&docType=kc&externalId=KB05327 , or enter apn values in the url as shown by @MusiGenesis